# Using value in state as component text

Tags: reactjs, react-props

I have a small app in which I need to use the same text string in a couple of places. I'm fairly new to react, and trying to figure out how to use the `appTitle` in `this.state` in the Header and Content components. I think it may make more sense to use `props`, but not sure if thats best way to implement this.

```
 const Header = () => (
  <AppHeader
    data-testid="app-header-default-example"
    position="static"
    renderNav={({ getNavProps }) => (
      <div {...getNavProps({})}>
      </div>
    )}
  />
);

const Content = () => (
  <div className="column-layout-example" style={styles.root}>
    <ColumnLayout container spacing={12}>
      <ColumnLayout item xs={4}>
        <Panel style={styles.panelLeft}><img src={leftImage} alt="logo"></img></Panel>
      </ColumnLayout>
      <ColumnLayout item xs={8}>
        <Panel style={styles.panelRight}><h1>{this.state.appTitle}</h1></Panel>
      </ColumnLayout>
    </ColumnLayout>
  </div>
);

const Main = () => (
  <ColumnLayout container>
    <Header />
    <Content />
  </ColumnLayout>
);

class App extends Component {
  constructor() {
    super();
    this.state = {
      appTitle: 'Notifications'
    }
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <ColumnLayout spacing={12}>
      <ThemedMain
        theme={lightTheme}
      />
      </ColumnLayout>
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will have to either pass it in as props or move Header and Content into the App class. This is because Header and Content do not have access to this.state object when it's outside of the App class.

Passing it down as a prop (you will need to pass it into Main and then into Header and Content):

```js
const Header = (props) => (
  <AppHeader
    data-testid="app-header-default-example"
    position="static"
    renderNav={({ getNavProps }) => (
      <div {...getNavProps({})}>
      </div>
    )}
  />
);

const Content = (props) => (
  <div className="column-layout-example" style={styles.root}>
    <ColumnLayout container spacing={12}>
      <ColumnLayout item xs={4}>
        <Panel style={styles.panelLeft}><img src={leftImage} alt="logo"></img></Panel>
      </ColumnLayout>
      <ColumnLayout item xs={8}>
        <Panel style={styles.panelRight}><h1>{props.appTitle}</h1></Panel>
      </ColumnLayout>
    </ColumnLayout>
  </div>
);

const Main = (props) => (
  <ColumnLayout container>
    <Header appTitle={props.appTitle}/>
    <Content appTitle={props.appTitle}/>
  </ColumnLayout>
);

class App extends Component {
  constructor() {
    super();
    this.state = {
      appTitle: 'Notifications'
    }
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <Main appTitle={this.state.appTitle}/>
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks, that works! I had to pass `appTitle={this.state.appTitle}` into `ThemedMain` in the render function and then `props` into the `ThemedMain` component.

Answer (score 0):

I'm assuming `ThemedMain` renders your `Content` component, if that assumption is correct then in `App` `render()` you'll need to pass `this.state.appTitle` into `ThemedMain` like so

```
<ThemedMain
  theme={lightTheme}
  appTitle={this.state.appTitle}
/>
```

Then inside of `ThemedMain` `render()` do something similar where you pass the `appTitle` to `Content` and access it from props

This approach can get tiresome after a point though, so when you get tired of it, I'd recommend looking at [react context](https://reactjs.org/docs/context.html)

Answer (score 0):

Your `App` component holds the `appTitle` in `state` and can pass it down to your `Header` and `Content` components via `props`. Seeing as those two components are rendered in the `Main` component, you'll have to pass `appTitle` to that component first. I don't see where you use `<Main />`, but assuming `<ThemedMain />` renders `<Main />` you can do the following:

In `App` render:

```
<ThemedMain
  theme={lightTheme}
  appTitle={this.state.appTitle}
/>
```

In `ThemedMain` render (I'm not 100% sure about this one unless you show the code for this component):

```
<Main appTitle={this.props.appTitle} />
```

Your `Main` functional component becomes:

```
const Main = props =>
  <ColumnLayout container>
    <Header appTitle={props.appTitle} />
    <Content appTitle={props.appTitle} />
  </ColumnLayout>
```

Now your `Header` and `Content` components can take `props` as an argument and have access to `appTitle` via `props.appTitle`

For larger apps, consider using [React Redux](https://github.com/reduxjs/react-redux) which will let you bypass this trickling down of props through components that do not need them.